# second layer nested automapper c# unflatten

Tags: c#, nested, automapper

I need help with the second layer nested automapper in C#.

I have classes as follow:

```
public class Event
{
    int EventId { get; set; }
    int EventName { get; set; },
    Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    int StudentId { get; set; }
    int StudentName { get; set; },
    Address Address { get; set; },
}

public class Address
{
    string AddressName { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
}

public class SourceEvent
{
    int EventId { get; set; }
    int EventName { get; set; },
    int StudentId { get; set; }
    int StudentName { get; set; },
    string AddressName { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; },
}

cfg.CreateMap<SourceEvent, Event>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Student,
                        o => o.MapFrom(
                            s => new Student
                            {
                                StudentId = s.StudentId,
                                StudentName = s.StudentName,
                            }
                        )
                        );
            });
```

how do I automap config from SourceEvent to Event with Student and Address?

I knew how to map the first level, but not sure how to map the second level (address class)

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer below to add the address class.

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceEvent, Event>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Student,
                    o => o.MapFrom(
                        s => new Student
                        {
                            StudentId = s.StudentId,
                            StudentName = s.StudentName,
                            Address = new Address   {
                              AddressName = s.AddressName,
                              City = s.City 
                             }
                        }));
        });
```